# jinja - TypeError: type Undefined doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: python, jinja2, typeerror

I'm getting the following traceback message with my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/app.py", line 470, in nutritionrda
    return render_template('nutritionrda.html', nutritiontotals=nutritiontotals)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/templates/nutritionrda.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/templates/base.html", line 63, in top-level template code
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/templates/nutritionrda.html", line 33, in block "body"
    <td class="col-xs-1">{{ ((nutritiontotal.calories)|round|int)}}</td><!-- Calories -->
  File "/Users/benjamattesjaroen/helloPython/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 797, in do_round
    return round(value, precision)
TypeError: type Undefined doesn't define __round__ method
```

It seems the issue starts as soon as I try and use the round method, here

```
<td class="col-xs-1">{{ ((nutritiontotal.calories)|round|int)}}</td><!-- Calories -->
```

I've printed the value of `nutritiontotal.calories` using a separate script and I get

```
1718.82
```

So why is this a 'type undefined' error? Isn't `1718.82` clearly a numeric value? (This script used to work but I was playing around with it and it broke in some way)

Comment: Did you try without those parenthesis? Something like `{{ nutritiontotal.calories|round|int }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that you are actually passing/rendering the value of that variable correctly? What happens if you do something like the following?

```
{% if nutritional.calories is defined %} 
{{ nutritional.calories|round|int }}
{% else %}
no value for nutritional.calories
{% endif %}
```

I've tried adding `{{ test|round|int }}` to the template and passing different values for `test` (int, string, float) to render_template and the way to reproduce the error is to not pass the value to render_template at all.